# Finding polynomials in Quotient rings with ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, quotient-spaces

Find a linear polynomial $A(x) ∈ (\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)[x]$ such that $$\bar A(x) = 2x^4 + x^3 + 2x + 1 \in (\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)[x]/(x^2 + x + 2)$$

Comment: I've tried using  x^2 = -x - 2 to get x^4 = 3x + 2 (congruent to  A¯(x)) however can't seem to get further than this point

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)[x]/(x^2 + x + 2)$, we have $x^2 = -x-2$. Use that to find other polynomials, of lower degree, that are congruent to $\bar A(x)$.